# Custom post type template and custom post page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have created custom post type "projects" in functions.php like this:

```
register_post_type('projects',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'projects',
            'singular_name' => 'project',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add new project',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit project'
        ),
        'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments'
        )
    ));
```

I've used add_action of course.
Then I've created two files.

1. template-projects.php
2. single-projects.php

Problem is, that when I go to: abc.com/projects - > I see index.php
When I go to abc.com/projects/project-1 - > I see detail of the project (this is somehow working). I tried to update permalinks via Settings, but it's not working. Before this update /projects was working, but /projects/project-1 wasn't.

Do you guys now how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct template for abc.com/projects is `archive-projects.php`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I think I shouldn't just blindly follow tutorials.

Comment: For reference, the proper naming of templates is outlined here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/